# c++) i have error when putting 1D array in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, clion

whats the prob

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int M; //height
    int N; //length
    cin >> M;
    cin >> N;
    int list[M][N], smaller[N];
    string smaller_str;
    for (int i = 0;i < M; ++i){
        getline(cin, smaller_str);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; i = i++) {
            cin >> smaller_str[j];
        }
        list[i] = smaller;
    }
}
```

i want to put 1D array "smaller" in to 2D array list
however i do get errors in the "list[i] = smaller;" part
i need help guys

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You cannot assign things to arrays (not elements of arrays). What do you want to do?

Comment: Also be careful fot this: [c++ - Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: int list[M][N], smaller[N]; // this is not valid c++, M and N must be constants. you need to use "new" to allocate the arrays

Comment: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @SvenNilsson no they dont need to use `new`. They can use `new` but shouldnt

Comment: i want to put array "smaller" as the element of array "list"

Comment: like {{6, 9}, {1,2,3}}

Comment: but you can't do that. Arrays do not work this way. You can copy the elements though

Comment: @SvenNilsson Using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is better.

Comment: @secret Please give some example input.

Comment: error: invalid array assignment
         list[i] = smaller;
                   ^~~~~~~

Comment: 3\n 
4\n 
3 10 8 14\n 
1 11 12 12\n
6 2 3 9

Comment: First you read a line with `getline(cin, smaller_str);`, then you read `N` characters to replace the characters in `smaller_str` (regardless of whether it has enough room or not). I suspect that you meant to use a `std::istringstream` created from `smaller_str` and read from that into `smaller`.

Comment: is there something like python's split() function in c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to check for errors, you won't need to use `getline` in this case. Just read each elements via `>>` operator.

Also note that Variable-Length Arrays like `int list[M][N];` is not in the standard C++. You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of that.

Another point is the the `i = i++` in the inner loop is wrong. It should be `++j`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int M; //height
    int N; //length
    cin >> M;
    cin >> N;
    //int list[M][N];
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > list(M, std::vector<int>(N));
    for (int i = 0;i < M; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            cin >> list[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign another arrays to an array, what you can do is copy/ move its content. For this, use `std::copy`,

```cpp
...
int list[M][N], smaller[N];
string smaller_str;
for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    getline(cin, smaller_str);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; i = i++) {
        cin >> smaller_str[j];
    }

    std::copy(smaller, smaller + N, reinterpret_cast<int*>(&list[i]));
}
```

Note: If you would like to move the content rather than copying, swap the `std::copy` with `std::move`.